# RewriteRule: subdomain and request don't start with X

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to redirect this url

```
http://cont1.cdn.example.com/news/test --> http://www.example.com/news/test
http://cont2.cdn.example.com/news/test --> http://www.example.com/news/test
```

but do not redirect if the url start with data...

```
http://cont1.cdn.example.com/data/images
```

I tried with this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cont(.*).cdn.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(data) - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

and the redirect works, but the browser says that it can't load the page because it doesn't redirect properly.

Answer (score 1):

Use that in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cont(.*).cdn.example.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/data
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```